# Tracing out the type of partial application of functions

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, partial-application

I have been inspecting the type of `Lens` to understand it and have trouble figuring out the *resulting type* of partial application there.

Initial type is like this: `type RefF a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)`

The above type applied for `Identity` functor becomes like this:

```
(b -> Identity b) -> (a -> Identity a)
```

Their modify function is defined like this:

```
modify :: RefF a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
modify r m = runIdentity . r (Identity . m)
```

I decompose the above definition individually to understand it better.

From above, the type of `Identity . m` is `b -> Identity b`

I even verified this using the typechecker:

```
check1 :: (b -> b) -> b -> Identity b
check1 m = Identity . m
```

Now, I try to formulate the type of `r (Identity . m)`. Here is where my mind becomes empty. The actual result of the partial application of `r (Identity . m)` seems to be `a -> Identity a` as typechecked below:

```
check2 :: RefF a b -> (b -> Identity b) -> a -> Identity a
check2 r che = r che
```

How does one figure this out mentally ? When I try to partially apply `che` to `r`, it doesn't seem to fit:

```
The type of `r` is   : (b -> Identity b) -> (a -> Identity a)
The type of `che` is : (b -> Identity b)
```

How does one trace out that the partial application of `r che` is `(a -> Identity a)`

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question—that all looks fine. `che` unifies with the first input argument type of `r` so `r che` works

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I got it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to partially apply che to r, it doesn't seem to fit:

`r` has type

```
(b -> Identity b) -> (a -> Identity a)
```

which means its first argument needs to have type `(b -> Identity b)`.

`che` has type

```
(b -> Identity b)
```

Just as `r` required, therefore `r che` will work and have type `(a -> Identity a)`.

After applied to the third argument, suppose it has been named `arg`, of `modify`, this `arg` has type `a`, `r (Identity . m) arg` will have type `Identity a`, after applied `runIdentity` on it, the result will have type `a`.

---

```
type RefF a b = forall f. Functor f => (b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)

modify :: RefF a b -> (b -> b) -> a -> a
modify r m = runIdentity . r (Identity . m)
```

You could infer the type of `modify r m` like this:

1. `r` has type `RefF a b`, which is `(b -> f b) -> (a -> f a)`
2. `m` has type `b->b`
3. `Identity` has type `forall a. a -> Identity a`, therefore `Identity . m` has type `b -> Identity b`
4. `r (Identity . m)` has type `a -> Identity a`, because `f` must be `Identity`
5. `runIdentity` has type `forall a. Identity a -> a`, therefore `runIdentity . r (Identity . m)` has type `a -> a`